# Matlab trimesh projection matrix

Tags: matlab, opengl, matlab-figure, projection

I'm working with a code base that uses Matlab's `trimesh` function to project 3D shapes to 2D images. The snippet that does this:

```
function h = plotMesh(mesh, style, az, el)
h = trimesh(mesh.F', mesh.V(1,:)', mesh.V(2,:)' ,mesh.V(3,:)', 'FaceColor', 'w', 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
    'AmbientStrength', 0.3, 'DiffuseStrength', 0.6, 'SpecularStrength', 0.0, 'FaceLighting', 'flat');
set(gcf, 'Color', 'w', 'Renderer', 'OpenGL');
set(gca, 'Projection', 'perspective');    
axis equal;
axis off;
view(az,el);
camlight('HEADLIGHT');
```

The above snippet is called as below:

```
ims = cell(1,length(opts.az));
for i=1:length(opts.az),
    plotMesh(mesh,'solid',opts.az(i),opts.el);
    ims{i} = print('-RGBImage', '-r100');  %in case of an error,you have an old matlab version: comment this line and uncomment the following 2 ones
    %saveas(opts.figHandle, '__temp__.png');
    %ims{i} = imread('__temp__.png');
    if strcmpi(opts.colorMode,'gray'), ims{i} = rgb2gray(ims{i}); end
    ims{i} = resize_im(ims{i}, opts.outputSize, opts.minMargin, opts.maxArea);
end
```

The `opts` data structure above is initialized as follows, two of the params being azimuth and elevation:

```
opts.az = [0:30:330];
opts.el = 30;
opts.use_dodecahedron_views = false;
opts.colorMode = 'rgb';
opts.outputSize = 224;
opts.minMargin = 0.1;
opts.maxArea = 0.3;
opts.figHandle = [];
```

I however, want the **[x,y,z]** to **[xImage,yImage]** mapping or the actual matrix used by `trimesh` to do this projection, so I can compute this mapping myself. I have additional labels in my mesh, associated with each **[x,y,z]** and I want to transfer those labels to the **[xImage,yImage]**. I can't do this unless I know the explicit 3D to 2D mapping. How do I get this mapping? The code base I use didn't set any camera parameters so the matrix used is intrinsic to Matlab's `trimesh` I think.

Note: Mesh is a data structure with a list of faces, vertices and normal, and is loaded from an 'OFF' file using this function defined here:
https://github.com/suhangpro/mvcnn/blob/abbebe3278fda70a42f62c2432ba6dd2247f072f/utils/loadMesh.m

TLDR; The mesh is plotted as 2D projection using `trimesh` and then plotting. For every [x,y,z] coordinate in the input, I want to know the [x,y] coordinate in the output image that it was mapped to.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] ?

Comment: Updated the question , let me know if anything else is needed?

Comment: Yes, a [mcve], if you read the description, needs to be complete. You do not give a `mesh`. Your example is not **Complete**, therefore not **Verifiable**.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Added link to the loadMesh function, which loads the 'off' file and creates a data structure with list of faces and vertices. Its a big code base, which can't be directly run. I'm posting snippets because the question pertains to something internal to Matlab, and not the codebase itself.

Comment: You are then saying you are not trying to provide a **Minimal** example that reproduces what you want, hitting 3/3 MCVE characteristics that you do not provide. I vote to close this question because it does not provide a MCVE.

Comment: The answer I'm looking for, is not code. I'd like to know how to reconstruct or reverse engineer the projection matrix. I'd also like to know if matlab maintains an internal mapping like that , as an attribute, that I can then read off. This is not a coding question; its a library/API question of what Matlab does in this particular case, and what attributes I need, to construct the matrix.

Comment: The answer is either use `getframe` or provide an example because its hard to figure out what you are trying to do when you refuse to show an example or what you are trying to do. Good luck.

Comment: Given an input 3D mesh and its corresponding 2D projection, obtained using `trimesh` and plotting, how do I know which 3D points in the input mapped to which 2D points in the output? For every point [x,y,z] in the input, I want the [x,y] in the output that it was projected to.